# I do not know how to keep it from cloning the delete button

Tags: jquery, clone, infinite

Hi I have been working on this for hours now but I still do not understand where I am going wrong 
this is what we were asked to do

4. Now add a button Delete to each new item (not to the first one). By clicking on this button, the corresponding item my-item, including item-header and item-body, is removed from the page, while the others are not affected

this is what I did

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="library/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    /*This task illustrates the sliding effects that can be produced
    with jQuery. Create a div with the class my-item that contains two 
    other divs, the first with the class item-header and the second
    with the class item-body. The item-header div contains an <h2> tag
    with some text (e.g. Click Me). The item-body div also contains some 
    text, but the div is initially hidden. If the user clicks on the 
    <h2> headline, the div item-body should slide down and its contents 
    become visible. After another click on the headline, the  div should 
    slide up and its contents become invisible

    Extend your code from the previous task in such a way that a deep 
    copy of the first div with the class my-item can be appended to the 
    body of the document by clicking on a button. Be sure to modify your 
    event handler from the previous task so that it also works for the 
    new elements.

    Now add a button Delete to each new item (not to the first one). By 
    clicking on this button, the corresponding item my-item, including 
    item-header and item-body, is removed from the page, while the 
    others are not affected.*/

        $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#copy').click(function(){
        $('.my-item:last')//i have to exclude the first 1
        .clone()
        .append( '<button id = "away">Delete</button>' )
        .appendTo('body')
        ;
        });

       $('.item-body').hide();

            $(document).on( 'click','h2', function() {

            if($(this).parent().next().is(':visible')){

            $(this).parent().next().slideUp();

            }

            else{

            $(this).parent().next().slideDown();

            }



        $(document).on('click', '#away', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();

        });   




        });













        });


    </script>
    </head>
        <body>
        <div class = 'my-item'>
            <div class = 'item-header'>
                <h2>Jesus is the only Hope</h2>
            </div><!--closing tag for for div item-header-->

            <div class = 'item-body'>
                <h2>I believe in Him</h2>
                <p>je leve les yeux vers les monts que jaime dou peut me venir ici le secours. Le secours me vient de lEternel meme</p>
            </div><!--closing tag for the div item-body-->

       </div><!-- This is the closing tag of div my_item-->
       <button id ='copy'>copy</button>

        </body>
</html>
```

Please could anyone give me any hint so that I know where I am going wrong?

Comment: One problem is that you create duplicate ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed the click event of `delete` button in the click event of `h2`. Put it outside of `h2` click event and in `$(documant).ready()`. Clone `$('.my-item:first')` instead of `$('.my-item:last')`, because from second `$('.my-item:last')` it's already have a delete.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#copy').click(function () {
                    $('.my-item:first')
                    .clone()
                    .append('<button id = "away">Delete</button>')
                    .appendTo('body')
                    ;
                });

                $('.item-body').hide();

                $(document).on('click', 'h2', function () {
                    if ($(this).parent().next().is(':visible')) {
                        $(this).parent().next().slideUp();
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
                    }
                });

                $(document).on('click', '#away', function () {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='my-item'>
            <div class='item-header'>
                <h2>Jesus is the only Hope</h2>
            </div><!--closing tag for for div item-header-->

            <div class='item-body'>
                <h2>I believe in Him</h2>
                <p>je leve les yeux vers les monts que jaime dou peut me venir ici le secours. Le secours me vient de lEternel meme</p>
            </div><!--closing tag for the div item-body-->

        </div><!-- This is the closing tag of div my_item-->
        <button id='copy'>copy</button>

    </body>
</html>
```